# Software for coding similar repetitive code e.g. in a for loop

Tags: programming

I have previously heard of a code that is useful for coding similar repetitive code e.g. a series of if statements in a for loop that are very similar. Rather than writing each statement manually you can write a generic statement and cycle through each value of a variable in a loop and the desired output. Wondered if anyone has heard of this kind of software.

Comment: can you provide a better example? Is this a language/duck typing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.